# Exit application programmatically

Tags: android, dialog

I have been searching for an answer but I couldn't find a proper one. The question is that I have a dialog themed activity on top of a normal activity. I would like to force the users to either read and click "OK" to the themed activity which will then transfer them to another dialog themed activity for some further questions or cannot enter the application. So, I would like to exit the application, on back press, and not just finish the themed activity that will reveal the content of my app. How is that possible?

Comment: can you please explain why that "dialog" is not real Dialog but Activity themed as dialog. I am sure that would give us better understanding so  we together can find the best solution for your case. Cheers

Comment: It is fully customized and contains many features that as far as I remember i couldn't do in normal dialog box

Comment: Oki.. Just wanted to understand better what are you trying to achieve with it, cause u said "I would like to force the users to either read and click "OK" to the themed activity or cannot enter" which sounded to me like a good reason to use custom Dialog.. Hope u will find solution which will work best for you. Cheers

Comment: After update of your problem description I add several things in 1st answer.. As I mention at the end I am not sure if bunch of dialogs are good idea but it's up to you to rethink about it or not. 

Anyway hope you already solved the problem ;) 
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`finish()` will do the perfect  job for you ;)

but make Dialog not cancelable..

**Edit (after problem description clarification)**:
As others said StartActivityForResult could work, with additional trick.
Because of the way you design your App (*DialogActivity1->DialogActivity2*), it might help to add following line in AndroidManifest file, for all your special dialog-look activities:

`android:noHistory="true"` or to set flag for intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` before u start DialogActivityN.

Both lines (from manifest or code) will make this actitivies not to stay on android stack, so when your MainActivity get result back, it will be result from last DialogActivity and than depending on result recieved you can either `finish()` or continue with execution of MainActivity..

when u start activities like this there is no need to call finish() to destroy them, u just start new activity and they will be gone from stack. Of course, in your case, last DialogActivity u will start with StartActivityForResult() and as I explained in previous paragraph MainActivity will do something  based on received results.

**However** making user goes through these dialogs several times at the beginning application, is not something I would consider good practice and it can make your user just give up and go for some less annoying app. (don't get this wrong, it's just my advice to rethink about concept)

Hope you will solve it ;) Cheers

Comment: `finish()` will finish the dialog themed activity revealing the content of my app.

Comment: is there any real reason you made it Activity (which look like dialog) and not real dialog?!

Answer (score 2):

If you start your dialog activity with `startActivityForResult()` you can send back the result `RESULT_CANCELED` from the dialog, and upon receiving this (in your main activity) you call `finish()`.

Comment: well... my dialog is actually a two paged one. So there are 2 activities. I can do that for the first one but what about the next activity?

Comment: In that case I would probably use Fragments to achieve the desired effect, but if that is not an option you have to find a way to send a value back to the first activity telling it whether 'OK' was clicked or not. possibly using a `SharedPreference`, as that would also allow your application to remember what the user picked last time?

Answer (score 1):

If you know about ActivityforResult then way is easier for you, First you need to start the dialog activity with method startActivityforResult... and then when dialog activity get close by back button you have to close it by Set result. In OnactivityResult method of start activity have to detect the same and close the same if setResult is not as according. Hope you got the point.